# Refresh highchart after hiding bar data

Tags: highcharts

How do I hide the bar data by clicking the bar and refresh the chart? I would like to have almost the same functionality as clicking on the legend.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Nadiyaka/005z7dut/1/

For example, if I click on 'Asia' bar, I want the data to become hidden and the chart to be reloaded to see other data bigger.

So far I'm able only to hide the data, but the chart isn't refreshing:

```
series: [{
        data: [1052, 954, 4250, 740, 38],
        events: {
          click: function(e) {
            var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
            index = event.point.x;
            chart.series[0].data[index].graphic.hide();
            chart.series[0].data[index].dataLabel.hide();
          }
        }
      }]
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the labels and the associated category or only the point?

Comment: Only the bar, because I would like to be able to toggle it back too

Comment: So you want to hide the bar and resize the chart horizontally and after clicking on the associated category make it visible again?

Comment: Yes, it's what I want, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option for hiding points (except the points in pie series), but you can achieve the same effect by setting the point's value to null.

```
  events: {
    click: function(e) {
      var point = e.point;

      point.series.chart.pointer.reset(false); // this is needed to prevent the tooltip from moving around
      point.update({
        y: null,
        holdY: point.y // I preserve original value needed on showing
      });
    }
  }
```

For showing the columns, attach events to labels

```
 load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        points = this.series[0].data;

      points.forEach(function(point) {
        chart.xAxis[0].ticks[point.x].label.on('click', function() {
          if (point.y === null) {
            point.update({
              y: point.holdY
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/005z7dut/2/

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation